# How to add NSIndexPath to NSUserDefaults in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift2, nsuserdefaults, nsindexpath

I am trying to save `NSIndexPath` at `NSUserDefaults`, but got the following exception:-

> Attempt to set a non-property-list object  {length = 2, path = 0 - 12} as an
>   NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key LastSelectedIndeX

My code:-

```
let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(selectedIndexPath, forKey: "lastSelectedIndex")
   NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

So how can I save `NSIndexPath` so that I can use it later on at another view controller.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't save directly indexPath in NSUserDefault. You can Store NSArray ,  NSDictionary , NSNumber , NSString and NSDictionary in NSUserDefault.

**Store IndexPath using `NSKeyedArchiver`:**

```
let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(selectedIndexPath)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(data, forKey: "indexKey")
```

**Get IndexPath using `NSKeyedArchiver`:**

```
let data1 = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("indexKey") as? NSData
let indexP1 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data1!) as! NSIndexPath
```

Comment: Well you don't *have* to store it as a dictionary.  You could encode the path in a string, using the form `"1.2.3.4"`.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by the others `(NS)IndexPath` is not property list compliant.

A solution is to use this simple extension of `UserDefaults` to save the `IndexPath` as an array of two integers

```
extension UserDefaults {

  func indexPath(forKey key : String) -> IndexPath?
  {
    guard let indexArray = array(forKey: key) as? [Int] else { return nil }
    return IndexPath(row: indexArray[0], section: indexArray[1])
  }

  func set(_ indexPath : IndexPath, forKey key: String)
  {
    set([indexPath.row, indexPath.section], forKey: key)
  }
}
```

You can find the syntax for an older Swift version in the edit history.

Comment: Why only two integers?

Comment: @trojanfoe Why not? The *simple* form is just `row` and `section`.

Comment: But an index path can be more than 2-levels deep.

Comment: @trojanfoe I know, but the question is clearly about `UITableView`

Answer (score 1):

This Swift code would work for any depth of IndexPath

```
extension UserDefaults {
    func indexPath(forKey key: String) -> IndexPath? {
        if let data = data(forKey: key), let indexPath = try? JSONDecoder().decode(IndexPath.self, from: data) {
            return indexPath
        }
        return nil
    }
    func set(_ indexPath: IndexPath, forKey key: String) {
        if let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(indexPath) {
            set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

Save like,

```
  var myDefaults: NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    var data: NSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(indexPath)
    myDefaults["lastSelectedIndex"] = myDefaults
```

Retrieve like,

```
    var data2: NSData = myDefaults.dataForKey("lastSelectedIndex")
    var indexPath2: NSIndexPath = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data2)
```

You have to convert indexpath to data then you can save and retrieve.

Hope this will help :)